# Remove "Attachments" folder after PHPMailer email is sent

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've got a web form which has a unique upload folder for each user (using their PHP session_id() as the folder name) which works well. When the form is submitted (after error checking) PHPMailer is used to send the email and the attachments. This is also working well. However, after the email is sent, I would like to remove the uploads from the folder and then the folder itself (sort of a self-cleanup!) The files are removed as expected but the folder remains (albeit empty). I wonder if the folder is somehow "still in use" so doesn't get deleted or something similar? This is the code:

```
            // Empty the contents of the upload folder
            if (is_dir($dir)) { // Target directory ($dir) is set above in photos POST section
                // Check for any files inside the directory
                $files = glob($dir.'/*'); // Get all file names
                foreach($files as $file) { // Iterate through the files
                    if(is_file($file)) { // Check its a file
                        unlink($file); // Delete the file
                    }
                }
                // Remove the upload folder
                rmdir($dir); //NOT WORKING? NEEDS SOME TROUBLESHOOTING...
            }
```

Any other ideas on why this folder is remaining?

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your folders might contain hidden files (starting with `.`) which [the default glob pattern won't match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#68869), so try this:

```
$files = glob($dir . '/{,.}*'); // Get all file names including hidden ones
foreach($files as $file) { // Iterate through the files
    if(is_file($file)) { // Check its a file
        unlink($file); // Delete the file
    }
}
```

Also check the return value on both unlink and rmdir so you can see exactly where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after much testing that the problem was not actually with rmdir at all! My web form uses a Dropzone for photo uploads to a unique folder for each user using their php session_id() and this folder is supposed to be created when they add a photo to Dropzone (if it doesn’t already exist). Problem was I’d put the folder creation code outside of the actual upload script so the folder was in fact being deleted but them instantly created again when the form submitted and the page reloads! Sorry about that but thanks for all your help. :)